# Add props from parent component in map() function from child component

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components. Parent and child. 
This is my child component:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const Users = (props) => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    let [respo, setA] = useState('name');
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
        console.log('effect')
    }, []);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const url = `https://api.github.com/users/hadley/repos`;
        const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
                mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
            }
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setUsers(data)
        // console.log(res)
    };
    fetchData();
    function mapping() {
        return (
            users.map((i, k) => <li key={k}>{i.props.details}</li>)
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {mapping()}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Users;
```

In my parent component i send a prop to  child:

```js
 <Tabs type="card">
 <TabPane tab="Tab Title 1" key="1">
 <Users details="name"/>
 </TabPane>
<TabPane tab="Tab Title 2" key="2">
 <Users details="id"/>
 </TabPane>
 <TabPane tab="Tab Title 3" key="3">
</Tabs>
```

I tried to access the props like here: `users.map((i, k) => <li key={k}>{i.props.details}</li>)` Why i cant access  the props from parent in map() function?

Comment: users is your state variable, you should access props directly - props.details

Comment: @Abhay Sehgal, how the map() will look?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you're trying to access the property given in `props.details` of each `user`.

Doing `i.props.details` will look for a property called `props` on the `user`. Instead, you can use a computed property with bracket notation like this:

```js
users.map((i, k) => <li key={k}>{i[props.details]}</li>)

// If the prop.details is 'name' it will be equivalent to
users.map((i, k) => <li key={k}>{i["name"]}</li>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using props incorrectly, use it like :

```
{props.details}
```

users is array you got from the api call and its items don't have props in them, if you want to access props in mapping function you should access it directly as I did above as it is available to mapping function through closure